# How can I ignore a field when marshalling a structure with P/Invoke

Tags: .net, structure, pinvoke, marshalling

I want to marshal a structure for use with P/Invoke, but this struct contains a field that is only relevant to my managed code, so I don't want it to be marshaled since it doesn't belong in the native structure. Is it even possible ? I was looking for an attribute similar to `NonSerialized` for serialization, but it doesn't seem to exist...

```
struct MyStructure
{
    int foo;
    int bar;

    [NotMarshaled] // This attribute doesn't exist, but that's the kind of thing I'm looking for...
    int ignored;
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to make the CLR ignore a field. I would instead use two structures, and perhaps make one a member of the other.

```
struct MyNativeStructure 
{ 
    public int foo; 
    public int bar; 
} 

struct MyStructure 
{ 
    public MyNativeStruct native; 
    public int ignored; 
}
```

Comment: "There's no way to make the CLR ignore a field" : yes, you're probably right... I'll wait a few days in case someone has another idea, but that's probably the best answer I'll get. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Two methods:

1. Use a class instead of a struct: structures are always passed by pointer to the Windows API or other native functions. Replacing a call to `doThis(ref myStruct)` with a call to `doThis([In, Out] myClass)` should do the trick. Once you've done this, you can simply access your not-to-be-marshaled fields with methods.
2. As i already stated, structs are (almost) always passed by reference: hence the callee knows nothing about structure dimensions: what about simply leaving your additional fields to be the last ones? When calling a native function that needs your structure's pointer and the structure's size, simply lie about its size, giving the one it would have without your extra fields. I don't know if it's a legal way to marshal such a structure back when obtaining it FROM a native function. *Side question: does the Marshaller process class fields marked as private? (I hope not...)*

Comment: Private field are also marshaled

Answer (score -1):

based on my tests, auto property like:

```
private int marshaled { get; set; }
```

will consume space while marshaling (`Marshal.SizeOf`)

But! explicitly specified property will not:

```
private int skipped
{
    get { return 0; }
    set { }
}
```

Comment: That's because your explicit property doesn't have a backing field. Fields take up space, methods and properties don't. Auto-properties have an implicit backing field.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque you abolutely right! so silly I forgot about auto-properties background